# Can't get Boostrap CSS to load in a React App

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is my HTML file:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/style.css') }}">
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.30.7/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dashboard</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/babel" src="/static/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The file is located in:

```
/Simple_flask_app
 -hello.py

  /static
    -js

  /styles
    -boostrap.min.css
    -style.css
```

I created a simple component just to try to get the CSS to load:

```
var Dashboard = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
         return (
             <div>
                 <div class="jumbotron">
                     <h1>Test</h1>
                 </div>
              </div>
             )

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I was trying to get this giant grey box to load - https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Do I have to do something special because I'm in React?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within JSX in React, you must use 'className' instead of 'class'.

So you should change `<div class="jumbotron">` to `<div className="jumbotron">`

Comment: do you know where the documentation is that has this? trying to figure out how to create ID, etc

Comment: Yep, it's mentioned in the React docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html